# Using loops inside llply (plyr package) in R

Tags: r, loops, plyr

I use a loop to delete specific rows in a dataframe that match a complex pattern. The loop works on a single dataframe.

I would like to use the same procedure for several dataframes that are stored in a list. Instead of writing another loop around this loop i thought of using plyr. But it does not work as expected.

Here is an example:

```
# create a list
testlist<-list(as.data.frame(Titanic),
               as.data.frame(Titanic))


# test
for(i in 1: nrow(testlist[[2]]))
  if(grepl("1st",testlist[[2]][i,1],perl = T)==TRUE)
    testlist[[2]]<-testlist[[2]][-i,] else 
      testlist[[2]]<-testlist[[2]]


testlist[[2]]
# works

# use plyr
testlist<-
llply(.data = testlist, 
    .fun = function (x) 
      for(j in 1:nrow(x))
        if(grepl("1st",x[j,1],perl = T)==TRUE)
          x<-x[-j,] else 
            x<-x
  )

testlist[[1]]
# returns NULL
```

Comment: Did you try defining your function before your `llply` and testing it with a single dataframe?

Comment: @Bernardo.  I just tried to define the function outside but it gives the same error. The object is NULL.

Comment: But did you try using your function without the `llply`, ie., on a single dataframe? The point is to find out whether the error is on your function or  in your `llply`

Comment: Thanks for your help. It did not work on a single dataframe. But after adding `return (x)` at the end it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The missing detail was `return(x)` at the end of the function.

```
testlist<-
  llply(.data = testlist, 
        .fun =   function (x){
          for(j in 1:nrow(x))
            if(grepl("1st",x[j,1],perl = T)==TRUE)
              x<-x[-j,] else 
                x<-x;
              return(x)}
  )
```